# How to use attributed Strings with cocos2d?

Tags: colors, cocos2d-iphone, label

how to use CCLabelTTF with ZAttributedString? 
Lets say I want a blue Text "Greetings to the World!" but I want the word "to" in red.

Answer (score 0):

ZAttributedString is part of FontLabel, an external library from Zynga that is packaged with Cocos2D.  FontLabel uses ZFont, not CCLabelTTF, etc ...

Refer to here: https://github.com/zynga/FontLabel

It would appear they provide some very small examples, and you can peek into their UnitTests as well to see additional use cases.