# Attributed labels in Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nsattributedstring, cclabelttf

**How can I create an attributed label in Cocos2d?**

Specifically I'm looking for a label where the color of each word can be unique. I read about [ZAttributed string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504858/how-to-use-attributed-strings-with-cocos2d) however the Github page no longer exists. Also searching the Cocos2d v2.1-beta2 codebase doesn't turn up anything for attributed string on iOS.

If nothing exists I'll probably just create my own object. I think everything would be straight forward except possibly the spacing between groups of words across a color change boundry.

Answer (score 2):

CCLabelBMFont label is a series of textures that can be manipulated like any normal sprite. You can run actions on them, transform them and change their color.

Letters are tagged by their position

```
CCSprite *gletter = (CCSprite*)[label getChildByTag:0];
```

Comment: Ok that sounds good! How can I create a CCLabelBMFont using a built-in font like Arial?